# add role to a mentioned user in discord.js v12

Tags: discord.js

code:

```
if(command === "rusr"){
    console.log((chalk.yellow)`You ran a command: rusr`)
    const id = args[0]
    const role = args.slice(1).join(" ")
    let user = message.guild.member(message.mentions.users.first()) || message.guild.members.get(id)
    user.roles.add(role)
}
```

error:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError [INVALID_TYPE]: Supplied roles is not a Role, Snowflake or Array or Collection of Roles or Snowflakes.
```

this is strange cuz i have the EXACT same code but with nickname which works just fine. anyway to fix this?

Comment: what exactly is the role you have in the command? is it a mention, an ID or just a name?

Comment: its a name, like this: -rusr (user mention here) role name

Comment: then you need to find that role first, you can't just add a role by name. It needs to be either an ID or a role object.

Comment: oh so like this? message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === args.slice(1).join(" "))

Comment: that would work. You can also access a role mention. Thats usually easier for the user. `message.mentions.roles.first()`

Comment: thanks i just tried it and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is in `const role = args.slice(1).join(" ")`. That's not the role, thats the name of the role. Instead make it something like

```
const role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name == args.slice(1).join(" "));
```

So that finds the role with the name specified.

It'll work without, but its good practice to also add `if(!role) return message.channel.send('Invalid role!');` after the line where you define role. This means if someone enters the name of a role that doesn't exist, it will stop and tell the user instead of breaking the code.